# Best way to handle parameters in inherited classes

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, parameters

I have a base class `ExportType` and several inherited classes that implement the specific data exportation.

The inherited classes need several parameters to define the way the data are exported from the database. These parameters can be different from a class to another.

So I thought to use a `Dictionary<string, string>` to handle the export parameters and in my base class I put a method like this:

```
public abstract void Export (Dictionary<string, string> exportParams);
```

Is this the best way to do it, or there are better ways to handle different parameters?

Comment: why don't you create a ConfigParamters Class and pass its object as paramter

Comment: @ShoaibShaikh do you mean a custom class to wrap the parameters?

Comment: Even the Exporting strategy logic is different for all the sub classes or same? 
If same, then let the base class handle the logic and make a property virtual whic accepts this parameters which are different for different sub classes.

Comment: yes you can wrap parameters in a class.. as @zenwalker said you can use inheritance if you want to create more specific parameter configs

Comment: How much parameters should be passed to method?

Comment: so, if I'm not wrong, I should have a `BaseExportParameters` base class and a different `SpecificExportParameters` class for each inherited export class... that's right?

Comment: @anatoliiG the number of parameters can vary... some classes don't need any parameter, others need 10 params or more...

Comment: What kind of parameter it could be(bool, int, decimal etc.)?

Comment: @anatoliiG Actually the parameters could be of any type... basically I handle string, int and bool values, but I'll convert each value to a string...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you cannot know for sure what parameters will a specific export type need, you have several options:

1. **Use a dictionary** (like you proposed): extensible, but no type safety
2. **Use an base class for the interface**: still no type safety, since you need to cast inside every specific export method.
3. **Make parameters implementation-specific and hidden from the caller**: preferred IMHO.

If you are hiding the concrete implementation of your export to your called through polymorphism, then you shouldn't expect them to know about your internal parameters.

I would simplify your export interface to:

```
interface IExport 
{
    void Export(); // or Export(string filename), alternatively
}
```

And then instantiating each concrete class the way you need:

```
// no params
IExport txt = new TextExport();

// single string (delimiter)
IExport csv = new DelimitedExport(",");

// lots of params
IExport excel = new ExcelExport(someStronglyTypedOptions);
```

This way your calling code doesn't need to bother with passing those parameters around.

**[Edit]**

To conclude: with no other apparent benefit, you can trivially solve the problem of the parameter type by rewriting this:

```
var csv = new ExcelExport();
csv.Export(parameters);
```

to this:

```
var csv = new ExcelExport(parameters);
csv.Export();
```

At one point, *someone* needs to know which parameters to instantiate and how to do it. This means that *everyone else* can accept an `IExport` instance from that point on, and be allowed nothing more than calling a plain parameterless method.

You concrete implementation will then have different constructors, and generally will follow this pattern:

```
class ExcelExport : IExport
{
    private readonly ExcelParams _params;
    public ExcelExport(ExcelParams parameters)
    {
        _params = parameters;
    }

    public void Export() 
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: This could be a good idea, but don't works for me. In my case the `Export` method of every specific export class can be invoked several times passing it different (specific) parameters, to obtain different reports of that specific type... Hope my explaination is clear...

Comment: @DavidC.: for each new parameter set, you simply create a new instance (pass the parameters through the constructor), but you do it earlier in your call stack, or inside a factory method. It's essentially the same, but the notion about the actual implementation can be hidden from the caller. The idea in this approach (and the usual idea with interfaces) is to make `IExport` public, provide a public `ExportFactory`, but hide all concrete implementations to make them inaccessible.

Comment: @DavidC.: If you don't approach it this way and let callers instantiate different parameter types, you might as well name each `Export` method differently; your caller obviously knows which concrete implementation it is dealing with. But it doesn't mean the dictionary based approach is wrong, it's just slightly less safe and prone to run-time errors.

Comment: I completely agree with your approach, I think it's the best idea, but I'm not so experienced with Factory pattern, so I'm trying to imagine how to adapt your solution to my problem...

Comment: @DavidC.: I've updated my answer. The point where you instantiate your export classes is basically your factory, and this is where usually parameters get injected into your concrete instances.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to apply your suggestion. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how it's called, you might be able to make the base class generic, taking in a type of a parameters class you create.

```
public abstract class BaseClass<TExportParams>
{
    public abstract void Export(TExportParams exportParams);
}

public class Derived : BaseClass<DerivedExportParamsClass>
{
    public void Export(DerivedExportParamsClass exportParams)
    {

    }
}
```

---

If you don't know the parameters type to pass to `Export` when you want to call it, then go with @Groo's answer.

Comment: I agree create an ExportModel base class to use and then inherit from that for each specific set of required values in their own class ExportWidgetDataClass

Comment: this solution might suffice - the main disadvantage is, that you cannot have eg a mixed list like `List<BaseClass<?>>` (where `?` is `Params1Class` **and** `Params2Class`) unless you introduce `BaseClass` and make it super of `BaseClass<T>`. even then you are not able to expose `Export(T t)` because you are missing the generic in the base-class. So you will have to add `Export(object obj)` and do a cast in the concrete implementations ...